# TAblEAU- HIVE table connection usinf ODBC driver

Tags: exception, connection, hive, syntax-error, tableau-api

actually i am trying to connect HIVE table and Tableau through HIVE ODBC driver , for this i create HIVE ODBC DSN and i am able to see in Tableau  all table which i had created in hive but while accessing those table i am getting error like

"[Cloudera][HiveODBC] (35) Error from Hive: error code: '0' error message: 'ExecuteStatement finished with operation state: ERROR_STATE'."

and i am not getting any Table value in Tableau

i already tried following

--tried to select the option "Use Native Query" (in advance option) when creating HIVE ODBC DSN and checked but still get errors.

--installed latest HIVE ODBC driver but still get errors

any help  ???

Comment: Are you able to query the HIVE data source directly using the same user name and password?

Comment: Hi Talvalin,      yes i can able to do that.                 -rashmikant

Answer (score 0):

1. connect method : Amazon Hive ODBC Driver
2. connect specitication: port 10000, database : hive
   and write a username, password
3. Test Connect
4. Congratuation > then  you can click the submit button